# How to make git branch's lastest codes same to another branch?

Tags: git

For example, I have branch dev and master. Now they are different on codes and some binary files. And I want to make the branch dev's last commit exactly same to master branch's last commit. How?

My method is:

```
git diff dev master --binary > 1.patch
git checkout dev
git apply 1.patch
```

Is there other easy way?

Comment: Do you want to merge master into dev?

Comment: @ParthS007  Not merge. Merge result is master branch's codes merged into dev branch. But then the two branch may be not exactly same.

Answer (score 2):

Branch are just pointers, you can set any ref to them

```
git branch -f dev master
```

which means they'll have the exact same history afterwards. *(as a sidenote, just checkout another branch before you move this one, or git will complain)*

Then again, if you needed to keep everything from `dev` which is not on `master`, this is **not** the way to go. ElpieKay's second solution will then work like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind losing `dev`'s own history,

```
git checkout dev
git reset master --hard
```

It makes `dev` point at `master`'s head.

If you want to keep `dev`'s own history,

```
git checkout dev
git merge $(git commit-tree -p HEAD -m "xxx" master^{tree})
# edit the commit message
git commit --amend
```

It creates a commit on `dev` and the commit has the same code with `master`.